# Change the function code after clicked once

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the event function after the its already clicked once? then in the second or more times it will behave differently.

I already tried the `one` event but I still want to have a function on that button if clicked but a different one.

**here's my code on one click event**

```
 $(document).one('click', '#search', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      that._getEmployeeProfile();
    });
```

**on second or above clicked I want to happen this**

```
$(document).on('click', '#search', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('searchlist').modal('show')
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a variable which will be updated if the user clicked on the element.

```
var userAlreadyClicked = false;

$(document).on('click', '#search', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  if(!userAlreadyClicked ){
    that._getEmployeeProfile();
    userAlreadyClicked = true;
  }else{
     $('searchlist').modal('show')
  }

});
```

Comment: Ill accept this as answer. its readable and you are the first one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain one variable as flag based on which you can execute the specific code block:

```
let flag = true;
$(document).on('click', '#search', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  if(flag){ //since the flag is true this code block will be executed only for the first click
    that._getEmployeeProfile();
    flag = false; //set the flag to false which will execute the else block for the subsequent click. 
  }
  else{
    $('searchlist').modal('show');
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a flag in your function and after first call of the function you can increment that number and then apply a check by if statement if the value of the flag variable is greater then one you can write another functionality 
e.g

```
 let flag = 0;
 $(document).on('click', '#search', function(e){
      flag++;
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      if(flag > 1){      
         $('searchlist').modal('show');
      } else {
         that._getEmployeeProfile();
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can data attribute in button tag and after first click you can change data attribute of that button.Below is example :

```js
$(document).on('click', '#search', function(e){
 var functionName = $(this).data('function');
 $this = $(this);
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
    if (typeof window[(functionName)] === 'function') {
        window[(functionName)]();
        $this.data('function','nofunction');
    } 
    else{
     $('searchlist').modal('show')
    }
});
```

```html
<button name="search" id="search"  data-function=""></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an X/Y problem. Let me guess at a better title.

"How can I show an existing profile if I already got it"

I would

1. assign the event handler to the submit of the form
2. store the user in a key/value store
3. If the user is not in the store, get the user
4. show the user from store.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple or unspecified number of elements whose behavior you want to change after a click, the next solution seems appropriate at least at first glance:

```
$(document).on('click', '#search', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var t = $(e.target);
    if (typeof t.prop('alreadyClicked') === 'undefined') {
        t.prop('alreadyClicked', 1);
        that._getEmployeeProfile();
    } else $('searchlist').modal('show');
});
```